# Convert matrix to tuple python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, tuples

I have a matrix called w and it looks like this:

```
in:  print(w)
out: [[0.0053691  0.00328692]]
```

it has a type <class 'numpy.matrix'>

```
in:  print(type(w))
out: <class 'numpy.matrix'>
```

I want it to be a tuple, but a simple w = tuple(w) is not doing the job done:

```
in:  w=tuple(w)
in:  print(w)
out: (matrix([[0.00624969, 0.00413867]]),)
```

But i want output to be like this:

```
in:  print(w)
out: (0.00624969, 0.00413867)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have a two-dimensional thing.

You can create a list like

```
>>> w.tolist()
[[0.0053691, 0.00328692]]
```

which is probably good enough. If you really wanted to extract a tulpe of the inner part

```
>>> tuple(w.tolist()[0])
(0.0053691, 0.00328692)
```

Comment: @mdurant, you may know something I don't but, is there any difference or advantage using your solution instead of mine?

Comment: That's fine too, and more compact - perhaps less clear. For any array of more than one element, I suspect that iteration would be slower.

Comment: @PabloC, `tolist` is the fastest way to 'extract' a numpy array (or `np.matrix`) to lists.  `*w` unpacking is like `list(w)` iterating on the **first** dimension of `w`, and usually slower.  Plus for this `w` the first dimension is size 1.

Answer (score 0):

You're "storing" the matrix into a tuple, not converting it. You can do the following

```
tuple(*w.A)
#(0.00624969, 0.00413867)
```

The *starred expression* (`*w.A`) unpackages outer dimension of the array values by iteration. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: But if `w` is `np.matrix`, as opposed to a 1d `ndarray`, this doesn't work.